# ORA-12505 Listener doesn't know I'd given in connect descriptor

Tags: oracle11g

I am doing java database connection through oracle database and I am facing ORA-12505 exception. I have checked my Oracle services they are running properly.

Comment: Is your TSNNAMES.ORA correctly configured ?

Comment: I am new at oracle db so I don't knw much about the configuration files such as tnsnames.ora ,listener.ora etc

Comment: Go to oracle installed folder in c drive oracle -> prodcut -> 11.2.0 -> client_1 -> network -> Admin, Go to this path and open TNSNAMES.ORA using notepad and check content of it. It should contain server name and port

Comment: Ya its written ...port, services ....in that ...but how to recognize that its correct ...or wrong...I am not a pro at it ...plz help

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have following Configuration in TNSName.ORA

```
FRO =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = blue.xyz.com)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = servername)
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
    )
  )
```

Your connection string should look something like this

```
 <add name="abc" connectionString="Data Source=FRO;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=def;Password=def;Unicode=True" providerName="System.Data.OracleClient" />
```